# How can I say "I feel nauseous"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The Lernu-dictionary has only one translation of *nauseous*, and that is *naŭza*, which means *disgusting*, but that's not what I want to say. How can I express something like *I feel sick* or *I feel nauseous*?

Answer (score 5):

Supozeble vi celas *Mi estas vomema; Mi sentas, ke mi devas vomi.*